# Viewing Google App Engine Python tracebacks in local development server due to error in Flask route

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

I'm developing a Flask app using Google App Engine and testing it on my local machine using the Local Development Server (ie `dev_appserver.py`).

When my app encounters a runtime exception at the top level of the app.py script, I see the traceback in the terminal running `dev_appserver.py`. However, when the exception is encountered inside a Flask route, it seems like either the dev server is catching and handling the exception. All I can see in the terminal output is that the route returns a 500 response status:

```
INFO     2017-06-20 13:18:31,998 devappserver2.py:116] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2017-06-20 13:18:32,025 api_server.py:297] Starting API server at: http://localhost:43843
INFO     2017-06-20 13:18:32,037 dispatcher.py:209] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2017-06-20 13:18:32,037 admin_server.py:116] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2017-06-20 13:18:36,048 module.py:809] default: "GET /cron/batch/basket HTTP/1.1" 500 291
```

One hacky way I can locate the traceback is by passing `dev_appserver.py` the flag `--logs_path=sqlite.db` and then viewing the contents of the `AppLogs` table in the sqlite file, which contains the traceback. But this is hardly a useful workflow.

Anyone know how I can get the traceback for an exception encountered in the handling of a Flask route?

Comment: I start `dev_appserver.py` in a terminal window and the logs stream in that window.  By default, the logs there will include all tracebacks.  What exactly do you see in the terminal window?

Comment: Interesting. I've updated the question with output that includes startup logging and the GET request to the route with the error.

Comment: That is where I see tracebacks. Add `assert False` to your code and see if that causes a traceback to be shown there.

Comment: Well some progress: I get a traceback if I introduce the error somewhere that is run on startup. But again, not when it's found inside inside the route. I guess the problem is that the exception is being caught and handled by the dev server or maybe Flask.

Comment: I've updated the question to reflect this new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to create a decorator which catches any exception, prints its traceback to stdout, and then re-raises the exception, which I then add to whichever routes I want to debug:

```
import traceback
import sys

def print_traceback(func):
    """Decorator that prints exception tracebacks to stdout"""
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception, e:
            print "Exception:"
            print "============================="
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            print "============================="
            raise e
    return wrapper

@app.route('/some/route')
@print_traceback
def some_route(task):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might help:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

production_environment = os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE').startswith('Google App Engine/')

if not production_environment:
    app.debug = True
```